# Hibernate Automatically load relationships

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the following Entity classes  UserEntity and TicketEntity. A User has many tickets and many tickets can belong to a user. My question is, is there a way to automatically load all the tickets belonging to a pertaining user by using Hibernate or do I have to manually load all the entity relationships from the DB? I think the .load() does this but I'm not quite sure. In my case could I do something like

userEntity.load()

Any help is appreciated, thanks

**UserEntity.java**

```
   package com.issuetracking.domain;

/**
 */
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@Column(name="user_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="username")
private String username;

@Column(name="email")
private String email;

@Column(name="password")
private String password;

@Transient
private String confirmpassword;

@Column(name="verified")
private boolean verified;

@Column(name="role_id")
private int role_id;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<TicketEntity> tickets;




//Getters/Setters

public List<TicketEntity> getTickets() {
    return tickets;
}

public void setTickets(List<TicketEntity> tickets) {
    this.tickets = tickets;
}

public int getRole_id() {
    return role_id;
}
public void setRole_id(int role_id) {
    this.role_id = role_id;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getConfirmpassword() {
    return confirmpassword;
}

public void setConfirmpassword(String confirmpassword) {
    this.confirmpassword = confirmpassword;
}

public boolean isVerified() {
    return verified;
}

public void setVerified(boolean verified) {
    this.verified = verified;
}

}
```

**TicketEntity.java**

```
 package com.issuetracking.domain;

import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name="ticket")
public class TicketEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name="ticket_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="title")
    private String title;

    @Column(name="description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="date_created")
    @Temporal( TemporalType.TIMESTAMP )
    private Date date_created;

    @Column(name="status_id")
    private int status_id;

    //private TicketStatus status;

    @Column(name="urgency_id")
    private int urgency_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    private UserEntity belongs_to;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id", insertable=false, updatable=false) 
    private UserEntity assigned_to;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getDate_created() {
        return date_created;
    }

    public void setDate_created(Date date_created) {
        this.date_created = date_created;
    }

    public int getStatus_id() {
        return status_id;
    }

    public void setStatus_id(int status_id) {
        this.status_id = status_id;
    }

    public int getUrgency_id() {
        return urgency_id;
    }

    public void setUrgency_id(int urgency_id) {
        this.urgency_id = urgency_id;
    }

    public UserEntity getBelongs_to() {
        return belongs_to;
    }

    public void setBelongs_to(UserEntity belongs_to) {
        this.belongs_to = belongs_to;
    }

    public UserEntity getAssigned_to() {
        return assigned_to;
    }

    public void setAssigned_to(UserEntity assigned_to) {
        this.assigned_to = assigned_to;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A User has many tickets and many tickets can belong to a user.

In this case relationship should be ManyToMany

> My question is, is there a way to automatically load all the tickets belonging to a pertaining user

Use EAGER FetchType instead of LAZY , Like

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<TicketEntity> tickets;
```